# Jenkins CI on local machine and GitHub integration

Tags: github, jenkins, local, webhooks

I set up Jenkins CI on local machine (with local IP) but I can't integrate it with GitHub. Is there any way to do it with this issue?

P.S. The task worked fine with the same settings when my local Jenkins CI was accessible outside the local network. But now I have no opportunity to make it public.

Comment: "I can't integrate it with GitHub" isn't a particularly helpful description; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. If you mean that webhooks from GitHub can't reach Jenkins because it's on an internal network, you'd need to add a firewall rule, or add a reverse proxy which can accept webhooks and forward them to Jenkins. Or fall back to having to use SCM polling.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Git Hub plugin to connect with the git repository and do build
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin